# Determining ANSI Terminal Escape Code Sizes

Tags: text, terminal, ansi-escape

I am writing a program that bascially gets terminal output, and needs to strip-out ANSI/VT-100 escape codes. I can find specs on the code(s) - but there are many, and they all have different sizes (numbers of characters).

Anyone know of an algorithmic way of figuring out the size of a given code? (i.e. Something like if "if it starts with a letter, it will be 2 chars, but if it starts with a symbol it will be one char").

Comment: Something like [this](https://superuser.com/q/380772/372008)? This uses a regular expression instead of trying to determine the length of escape codes.

Comment: That only deals with a specific (set of) the codes.